# Spring - How to call secured service via feign without a user

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-feign

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway and lots of services which more or less depend on each other. A Angular-Client communicates with the services via the gateway. The gateway and services (resource-servers) are secured with OAuth2 and tokens are provided by an external Auth-Server.
To make calls between the services we use feign. We use a RequestInterceptor for feign to forward the users token between the services.
But: Some services use AMQP to create events when a endpoint was called. In the services which listen for events again other services are being called. As there are no Security-Contexts attached to incoming messages these calls run on 401-Errors.

Is there any way to attach a security-context to AMQP-Messages or any way to let Feign get a token via client_credentials-grant?

- **Spring-version: 2.3.5**
- **Spring Cloud: Hoxton SR9**

Answer (score 0):

As stated in many other sources the OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor is a possible solution for that problem. I was afraid of using it, as it is marked as deprecated. I just saw that the comment says "will move to Spring Cloud Openfeign in next major release."

As this means we'd just have a shift in dependencies it should be no problem to use the following solution:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignConfig {

    private ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResource() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();

        resource.setAccessTokenUri(<TOKEN_ENDPOINT>);
        resource.setClientId(<CLIENT_ID>);
        resource.setClientSecret(<SECRET>);
        resource.setGrantType("client_credentials");
        resource.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);

        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor() {
        return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(), clientCredentialsResource());
    }
}
```

With Spring Security 5 and OAuth2 dependencies there are no other annotations needed if you just use the `http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()` chain in your WebSecurity-configuration as I learned from this great article: https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/11/spring-cloud-gateway-with-openid-connect-and-token-relay/